# Obfuscation for a custom iOS framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, obfuscation

I made an iOS framework that is written in C++ and wrapped with objective c.

How can I obfuscate my framework before I deliver it?

Answer (score 0):

You can strip down the symbols for it. That will make sure no one can dig through the code. But it will seriously hinder crash reporting